# Typescript and Mongoose Model

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, model

I 'm trying to bind my Model with a mongoose schema using Typescript.
I have my IUser interface:

```
export interface IUser{

   _id: string;

   _email: string;
}
```

My User class:

```
export class User implements IUser{
  _id: string;
  _email: string;
}
```

My RepositoryBase:

```
export class RepositoryBase<T extends mongoose.Document> {

 private _model: mongoose.Model<mongoose.Document>;

  constructor(schemaModel: mongoose.Model<mongoose.Document>) {
     this._model = schemaModel;
  }

 create(item: T): mongoose.Promise<mongoose.model<T>> {
    return this._model.create(item);
 }
}
```

And finally my UserRepository which extends RepositoryBase and implements an IUserRepository (actually empty):

```
export class UserRepository  extends RepositoryBase<IUser> implements     IUserRepository{

  constructor(){
    super(mongoose.model<IUser>("User", 
        new mongoose.Schema({
            _id: String,
            _email: String,
        }))
    )
  }
```

}

Thr problem is that typescript compiler keeps saying :
*Type 'IUser' does not satisfy the constraint 'Document'*

And if I do:

```
export interface IUser extends mongoose.Document
```

That problem is solved but the compiler says:
 *Property 'increment' is missing in type 'User'*

Really, i don't want my IUser to extend mongoose.Document, because neither IUser or User should know about how Repository work nor it's implementation.

Comment: See if this helps: https://github.com/Appsilon/styleguide/wiki/mongoose-typescript-models

Comment: Thanks Harry, that was very useful. But the "export mongoose.model<IUserModel>("User", userSchema)" i should do it in my User class. But then i loose all my methods, isn't it?

Comment: Stuck with the same issue. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 11):

I solved the issue by referencing [this blog post](https://know-thy-code.com/mongoose-schemas-models-typescript/).

The trick was to extends the `Document` interface from `mongoose` like so:

```
import { Model, Document } from 'mongoose';

interface User {
  id: string;
  email: string;
}

interface UserModel extends User, Document {}

Model<UserModel> // doesn't throw an error anymore
```